# plotting molecule in R with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have two dataframes, shown below, which represent a molecule. I want to produce a plot of this molecule with `plot_ly`.

One dataframe, `df`, contains coordinates and element type. 
The other dataframe, `conn`, contains connection structure between the atoms, and the number of bonds, (1, 2, or 3), which connect two atoms. 
For example, from row two of `conn`,  atom 55 connects to atom 54 with a double bond.

```
head(df)
  atomId element     xCord     yCord     zCord
1     54       C -16.47474 -14.96508  8.332247
2     55       C -15.43503 -14.37500  7.599300
3     56       C -15.03843 -13.23943  8.285489
4     57       C -15.82452 -13.17686  9.413819
5     58       N -16.68804 -14.21907  9.439404
6     59       H -17.41647 -14.37430 10.166242

head(conn)
    atom1 atom2 order
135    58    54     1
136    55    54     2
137    71    55     1
138    70    56     1
139    55    56     1
140    58    57     1

df <- structure(list(atomId = c("54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"69", "70", "71"), element = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "N", "H", 
"H", "H", "H"), xCord = c(-16.474736, -15.43503, -15.038428, 
-15.82452, -16.68804, -17.416475, -15.788173, -14.29002, -15.038094
), yCord = c(-14.965081, -14.375, -13.239429, -13.176858, -14.219065, 
-14.374302, -12.380838, -12.509718, -14.671816), zCord = c(8.332247, 
7.5993, 8.285489, 9.413819, 9.439404, 10.166242, 10.151304, 7.979794, 
6.636516)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

conn <- structure(list(atom1 = c(58, 55, 71, 70, 55, 58, 56, 69, 59), 
    atom2 = c(54, 54, 55, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 58), order = c(1, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)), row.names = 135:143, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot this molecule in R. I was able to make a 3D scatter plot, but I am having a hard time plotting the bonds.

```
plot_ly(x = df$xCord, y = df$yCord, z = df$zCord, type="scatter3d", 
        mode="markers", color = df$element, hoverinfo = "text",
        text = paste('AtomId: ', df$atomId, "\nElement: ", df$element)
```

[image]

I really like this plot because it is interactive, and I can annotate the points. However, I would like to draw lines between the connections. I would like to show bond lines, such as in this image, however, I actually prefer the dots in plotly instead of giant ugly 3D spheres, as in the second picture.

[image]

Can anyone help me represent the bond lines in Plotly, or some other comparable package? Worst case I understand if they have to be color coded, or encoded with dashed/solid lines, ect. Id prefer to see double lines for a double bond, but will take what I can get.

Thanks!